# Elasticsearch: terms aggregations on doubly nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a doubly nested aggregation on a doubly nested object. That is, I have the root document, a child property, and a grand-child property. To be more precise, I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "root": {
      "properties": {
        "fields": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "selections": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to aggregate selection value counts per field, or in other words, to count the number of occurrences of each value for each field name, accross all root objects.

I have this:

```
{
  "query": {
      ...
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "fields": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "fields"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "fields.name"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "values": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "selections"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "selections.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gets the field names as I want but for each of them I get no doc counts for the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give full name for inner nested field, Change "path":"selections" to  "path":"fields.selections"

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggregations": {
    "fields": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "fields"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "fields.name"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "values": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "fields.selections"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "fields.selections.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "fields" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "name" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "abc",
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "values" : {
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "value" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : "1",
                    "doc_count" : 2
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks fixed my issue, thanks a lot!
To anyone who comes across this, I also made the mistake of including the second aggregation level outside of `name`, whereas it should be inside, just after `terms`